# How to initialize value in model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this class:

```
public class TicketPayoutModel 
{

    public string Logo { get; set; }     
}
```

in MainModel I have this :

```
public TicketPayoutModel TicketPayOut { get; set; }
```

I do this :

```
 TicketPayOut = new TicketPayoutModel();
 TicketPayOut.Logo = "test";
```

and when I try to call this in view like this: `@Model.TicketPayOut.Logo` I get an null. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestion?

EDIT: this is my controller:

```
  public ActionResult PayOutConfirmation()
  {
     return View(new TicketPayOutModel());
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the controller action that initialises `TicketPayOut`? How is `return View()` called?

Comment: in your `TicketPayoutModel` class, you need a constructor. Add `public TicketPayoutModel() { this.Logo = ""; }` before the class closing braces. The`this.Logo = "";` part is optional.

Comment: @JasonEvans i posted my controller

Comment: just add a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise your value inside constructor of your model.

```
public class TicketPayoutModel 
{
    public TicketPayoutModel()
    {
        this.Logo = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Logo { get; set; }     
}
```

Or using new C# 6 variant:

```
public class TicketPayoutModel 
{
    public string Logo { get; set; } = string.Empty;     
}
```

Also you can initialise your value through constructor's argument:

```
public class TicketPayoutModel 
{
    public TicketPayoutModel(string logo)
    {
        this.Logo = logo;
    }

    public string Logo { get; set; }     
}

public ActionResult PayOutConfirmation()
{
    return View(new TicketPayOutModel("logo.png"));
}
```

Comment: is it possible to avoid initialize in controller? That i do somthing like this in class:  TicketPayOut = new PayOutTicketModel("~/Content/img/logo.png");

Comment: @None actually you trying to get value in your View file - like this @ Model.Someproperty.SomeSubProperty - this reference trying to call your object that you putted into you controller - this.View(new ModelClass()).  As I see your question has a little confusion about Model class and model properties. Could you please provide full code of your model ? Then I will be able to help you with your controller. ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Model.Logo not @Model.TicketPayOut.Logo

And to test, you could just 
return View(new TicketPayOutModel{ Logo = "foo" });

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you controller, you are passing a new `TicketPayOutModel` instance to your view, the logo property of this is not initialized, so it will give `null`.

Modify your controller method with something like this -

```
  public ActionResult PayOutConfirmation()
  {
     var ticketPayOutModel = new TicketPayoutModel();
     ticketPayOutModel .Logo = "test";
     return View(ticketPayOutModel );
  }
```